# Adding cpp files to cocos2d-x project android project

Tags: java, android, c++, eclipse, cocos2d-x

I've followed this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/33750/cocos2d-x-tutorial-for-ios-and-android-getting-started, and managed to create an android hello world project in cococs2d-x. Now when I add anything to my classes directory and try to use them, I get errors like

```
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/libgame.so] Error 1
undefined reference to 'ConstAndStats::getDevice()'
```

How should I fix these problems, and add the already working codes (in Xcode) for my eclipse project?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This kind of error may appear if you add a class to the classes directory but forget to add it to the Android.mk file from the jni folder. Add something like this:

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hellocpp/main.cpp \
          ../../Classes/YourClass.cpp \
          ../../Classes/YourLastClass.cpp
```

Comment: yeah I thought that the problem is something like this, now that I added the correct cpp file I got this error: 

make: *** No rule to make target `jni/../../Classes/ConstAndStats.cpp', needed by `obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/game_shared/__/__/Classes/ConstAndStats.o'.  Stop. asad    C/C++ Problem

Comment: ok my class name is ConstsAndStats.cpp not ConstAndStats.cpp (plural), so it was a mispelling. thanks!